# Is this a Boggle pad?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, boggle

Given a list of case-insensitive ASCII letter strings ("words"), output whether the entire list can be found on some four-by-four configuration ("board") of letter squares, in which no square can be used more than once in a word, and in which words are formed by moving from any square to any adjacent square including diagonally.

You do not need to worry that the combination of squares that would allow for the list actually appears in a [Boggle](/tags/boggle/info) game. The words need not be actual words in any language. You should assume that if Q appears on the board, it's on a square of its own (unlike in actual Boggle).

Standard loopholes are banned, standard I/O rules apply, and you're golfing.

---

In the examples below, a slash signifies a newline.

### Truthy examples

- auuuuooiiaaoiee, euiaaiueeuua, ooouuueee, eueueuoaoa — All are on the board auii/euoa/ueoa/euio
- swiop, byteba, ceropl, qoiz, aeis, lqoep — All are on the board abcb/rety/poiw/lqzs

### Falsy examples

- swiop, byteba, ceropl, qoiz, aeis, lqoep, wybez — There are fifteen distinct letters (*abceilopqrstwyz*) and a single word has two *b*s, so that's the sixteenth square. Thus there's only one *e*. But the *e* has nine distinct letters (*abcioprtz*) adjacent to it, which is impossible.
- hskcbnzvgfa, lajdnzvfhgs, kajfbmxvshd, ldgckvbsanx — There are sixteen distinct letters (*abcdfghjklmnsvxz*). Of those, *s* is adjacent to all of *abghkv*, *v* is adjacent to all of *bfgksxz*, *b* is adjacent to all of *cfmnsv*, *a* is adjacent to all of *fjklns*, and *f* is adjacent to all of *abghjv*. But on an actual board only four squares are adjacent to more than five squares apiece.

Comment: I can understand the challenge clearly and unambiguously. If anyone disagree (and VTC as unclear), consider leaving a comment.

Comment: I wonder if it would be better suited for [`fastest-code`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) or [`fastest-algorithm`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm). As `code-golf`, it may lead to brute-force solutions that run forever and never actually return anything.

Comment: (Or you may consider adding a time limit if you decide to keep it as `code-golf`.)

Comment: @Arnauld, I don't like fastest-code challenges, personally, and don't know enough compsci to understand or judge fastest-algorithm challenges. That said, I'm considering making a note in the challenge that no brute-force answer will get the checkmark, even if it's shortest in its language.

Comment: You'd need to define what _brute-force_ exactly means. But even so, I'm not sure it's a good idea. A very clever answer may still use brute-force in some way.

Comment: Besides that, I too think that the challenge is clearly defined. So, people that have VTC really should share their thoughts.

Comment: @msh Not accepting any answer is an option.

Comment: @Arn Both codegolf and fastestcode are interesting in their own way. You can post fastestcode if you want.

Comment: As far as I can see, in general this is a subgraph problem, which is NP complete, so all non-magical answers will need some degree of brute force.

Comment: I haven't VTC, but the question didn't make sense to me until I read up on what Boggle was and what its rules were. Perhaps a short description that would make sense to someone who doesn't know Boggle, and better formatting of the board (auii/euoa/ueoa/euio) in 2D, would help clarify the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 215 bytes

```python
def f(w):b=product(*[set("".join(w))]*16);return any(all(any(all(x-y in[1,-1,4,-4]for x,y in zip(q,q[1:]))for q in product(*[[x for x in range(16)if k[x]==c]for c in a]))for a in w)for k in b)
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/BboMwDL33KyxOCQqV0KodOvEliIMLZvNK4xASFfbzLGGbZh/8/N6zLbstfIh92feBRhjVU19vjfMyxD6osl0oqKI4fwrbJOmurF/1m6cQvQW0m8JpUn91rTZg29amqs3FVJduFA@rySR8sVOzmdv62mmd@Tmz/3faFQ53Zj3ad1LpEI9wb9euafpjVZ9F/J3H3DwPeM/wpk@jlwdwIB9EpgX44cSHcn@KHxZoksnFoPR5cROnpwwU@uQ826DS19mj9Y4xhQgzojCRAYoJciSKEQ2ISNLpR8gpKPgN)

This is never going to finish, so I can't really debug it or prove it works. I will try to find constant optimizations / test with reduced test cases, but if you spot a reason it would definitely fail, I will take it down / fix it.